# Feynman diagrams with TikZ-Feynman: too big gap between particle label and external line

Tags: labels, tikz-feynman

When I increase the size of my diagram with "scale" the gap between the particle label and the external line increases too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{luatex85} 
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-pdftex.def} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram [scale=2.5][horizontal=a to b] {
i1 [particle=$e^{-}$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
a -- [photon] b,
f1 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)],
};
\end{center}
```

However if I use the "large" option the gap remains the same but "large" option is still not large enough for me.

```
\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to b] {
i1 [particle=$e^{-}$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
a -- [photon] b,
f1 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)],
};
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

So how can I resolve the gap problem by still using the "scale" option (or another option which guarentees the same size) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main ways in which you can achieve that in [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)).

## Defining an `extra large` style

Just like `large` and `small` are defined in Ti*k*Z-Feynman, you can define new styles.  In particular, you can adapt the style from `large` and make you own `extra large` style.  The `large` style is (essentially) defined to be:

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
  large/.style={
    /tikz/node distance=2cm,
    /graph drawing/node distance=2.5cm,
    /graph drawing/level distance=2cm,
    /graph drawing/sibling distance=3cm,
    /tikz/graphs/edges={thick},
    /tikzfeynman/every dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=2mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every crossed dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=4mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every blob@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=1cm},
    /tikzfeynman/arrow size=1.6pt,
    /tikzfeynman/insertion/size=4pt,
  }
}
```

So taking all the distances and doubling them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzfeynmanset{
  extra large/.style={
    /tikz/node distance=4cm,
    /graph drawing/node distance=5cm,
    /graph drawing/level distance=4cm,
    /graph drawing/sibling distance=6cm,
    /tikz/graphs/edges={very thick},
    /tikzfeynman/every dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=4mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every crossed dot@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=8mm},
    /tikzfeynman/every blob@@/.append style={/tikz/minimum size=2cm},
    /tikzfeynman/arrow size=3.2pt,
    /tikzfeynman/insertion/size=8pt,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [extra large, horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 [particle=$e^{-}$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The problem here is that the lines are becoming comically large compared to the size of the text.  The font size can be adjusted by adding `/tikz/node font=\huge` to the style in which case the output becomes a lot more reasonable:

[image]

The issue is still that the photon line is quite small which I don't really like.  You can keep modifying the `extra large` style to fix this, but you'll have to do this for the gluons, the scalars, etc.

## Using `\scalebox`

An alternative is to use a scale box around the diagram which scales all of the content by the specified scale factor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\scalebox{2}{
  \feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
    i1 [particle=$e^{-}$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)],
    a -- [photon] b,
    f1 [particle=\(\mu^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\mu^{-}\)],
  };
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

In this instance, everything is scaled by a factor of 2 including the text and the size of the sine wave in the photon line.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly well and thank you for  TikZ-Feynman, this is absolutely great.